# How to reactivate bootstrap carousel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a bootstrap carousel on the homepage of my rails app which is hosted at Heroku. It works fine when the page initially loads. However, if I go to another page, then go back to the homepage, the carousel does not cycle unless I click on one of the left or right chevrons. I guess this is normal but how can I make the carousel cycle automatically when I link back to the homepage from within the app. I am getting bootstrap via cdn:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

and javascript/jquery from:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it could be due to using turbolinks. If you are, the easiest solution is to try [disabling turbolinks](http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4) and see if that fixes the problem.

If that solves it, the reason is that Bootstrap probably sets up it's carousels and other stuff on `document ready`, which fires only once per page load. Turbolinks makes it so going to another page doesn't trigger a full page load - it pulls the new content in via ajax, and so Bootstrap's javascript (which sets up the carousel) will not be executed when you come back to the home page from another page - even though it does load when you view the home page directly.